# JavaScript SpeechSynthesis API How to make the voices close to the human voice

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech

I'm working on "Text To Speech" famous JavaScript **SpeechSynthesis** API. I found 2 Microsoft voices installed on my 'Windows 10' and about 10 voices from Google. all of them looks like robotic voices. I tried tuning the rate and pitch, but none of them helped to bring them close to human voice.

I also noticed that SpeechSynthesis API requires users to have some voices installed on their own device to make the API work.

My Question is,

1. Can we make the voices more close to the human voice?
2. Is there any alternative of SpeechSynthesis to use one nice voice across the devices, like, we install the voice on serverside and use that one for playing the audio?

bellow is the sample code.

```
var synth = window.speechSynthesis;
var voices = synth.getVoices();
var utterThis = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('Hello World. Please speak this dummy text');
utterThis.voice = voices[0]; // <-- try with any random voice
utterThis.pitch = 0.8;
utterThis.rate = 0.7;
utterThis.volume = 1;
synth.speak(utterThis);
```

List of voices fetched by `getVoices()`

[image]

UI Interface to tune the rate and pitch etc

[image]

Comment: "Can we make the voices more close to the human voice?" - Not trivially, similar to asking "Can you make a browser better than Edge or Chrome" . "Is there any alternative of SpeechSynthesis to use one nice voice across the devices, like, we install the voice on serverside and use that one for playing the audio?
" - I doubt this could be currently done in a practical manner, the mechanics of collecting the text, passing to the server and getting the audio back in a timely matter would be problematic.

Comment: hmm, good point! thank you for the comment.